# JSON format for Single property case classes

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

Given

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)
case class Resident(location: Location)
```

What is the easiest way of writing a JSON formatter for `Resident`

I am trying to use the `FunctionalBuilder` i.e

```
val residentFormats: Format[Resident] = (
(JsPath \ "location").format[Location]
) (Resident.apply, unlift(Resident.unapply))
```

but using it with a single property case class is turning out to be not easily possible. My subsequent attempts are tending to involve a lot of code than I think is necessary.

Would appreciate some pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
object Resident {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Resident] = Json.format[Resident]
}
```

Or you can split definitions:

```
object Resident {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Resident] = Json.reads[Resident]
  implicit val writes: OWrites[Resident] = Json.writes[Resident]
}
```

You can define `reads` and writes by yourself:

```
object Resident {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Resident] = json => {
    (json \ "location").validate[Location].map(Resident(_))
  }
  implicit val writes: OWrites[Resident] = resident => Json.obj("localtion" -> resident.location)
}
```

**Note:** If you need to convert name from *camelCase* to *underscore_keys*, you can define implicit `JsonConfiguration`:

```
object Resident {
  implicit val jsonConfig = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)
  implicit val format: OFormat[Resident] = Json.format[Resident]
}
```

Comment: How would you go about reading JSON keys in the following format `Location`, `ResidentLocation`, I reckon I would have to write a custom `JsonConfiguration`?

Thanks for pointing out the `JsonConfiguration` aspect by the way, I had never used it!

Comment: @ivanorone is it better to ask question about custom naming in separate question, so that other users can find answer easier. Create a question and send me a link

Comment: @ Andrii Abramov, true, however, it is actually something minor, I figured it out on second look. I don't think I need to ask a question about it. Will keep what you have said in mind next time. For those following;
`object Capitalize extends JsonNaming {def apply(property: String): String = property.capitalize; override val toString = "Capitalize" }`

Comment: @ivanorone yep, exactly! And then pass it to `JsonConfiguration`

Comment: `JsonNaming(_.capitalize)` as functional factory